# Remove Row from Custom ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Ok so I've searched around on SO for a bit but can't seem to get an answer to work. This one is close, but it removes the last item in the list and then crashes when I remove the last value. I just want to have a button from inside of the list row perform an action based on the content in the list, and then remove that row from the list. Thank you!

```
public class CitrusListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CitrusList>
{

//Globals
Context context;
int layoutResourceId;
ArrayList<CitrusList> data = null;

//Create the list item row
public CitrusListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<CitrusList> listItems)
{
    super(context, layoutResourceId, listItems);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.data = listItems;
}

//Expand and place items for List View onto calling page in ListView
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    CitrusListHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ( (Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new CitrusListHolder();

        //holder.txtTitle = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.CitrusListTitle);
        holder.colorSpinner = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.color_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                R.array.colors_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.colorSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

        holder.textureSpinner = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.texture_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> texture_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                R.array.texture_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.textureSpinner.setAdapter(texture_adapter);

        holder.soliditySpinner = (Spinner)row.findViewById(R.id.solidity_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> solidity_adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getContext(),
                R.array.solidity_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        holder.soliditySpinner.setAdapter(solidity_adapter);

        Button rateButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.rate_button);
        rateButton.setTag(position);
        rateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Integer index = (Integer) v.getTag();
                data.remove(index.intValue());
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        row.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (CitrusListHolder)row.getTag();
    }

    CitrusList SingleLine = data.get(position);
    //holder.txtTitle.setText(SingleLine.title);
    return row;
}

//Stores the values of the items in the list view
static class CitrusListHolder
{
    //TextView txtTitle;
    Spinner colorSpinner;
    Spinner textureSpinner;
    Spinner soliditySpinner;
}
}
```

Comment: how do you remove the data from array?

Comment: are you setting `Integer` as Tag to `Button`?

Answer (score 5):

you can remove the item from the array list by using `remove()` method and then call the `notifyDataSetChanged()` method of adapter.

Comment: OP has removed the item and called the `notifyDataSetChanged()` from `onClick()` of the `Button`

Comment: I'm not sure how what you're saying is different from what I have in my code. Can you elaborate?

Comment: For anyone else looking for this. I wrote a custom adapter for a layout that looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26373402/how-do-i-roll-out-this-view-in-my-android-application and had a similar issue. In my listener, after the asynchronous call to delete returned successfully, I just used the following code `comments.remove (position);` and then `notifyDataSetChanged ();`. My listener, was implemented right in the `getView ()` in my custom adapter and in my design, `comments` is the `ListView` loaded as `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>` into my `BaseAdapter` subclass.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should try this

```
rateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int index = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString())
            data.remove(index);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Nope same issue with this set. Thank you though.

Comment: @ Jignesh Ansodariya  +1 it works for me thank you (We have to set position as tag while adding component in getView method)

Answer (score 1):

To remove a row from a ListView, You modify the data held by the Adapter that is controlling the ListView. If the adapter is an `ArrayAdapter`, call `remove()` on the `ArrayAdapter` and give it the position of whatever item you need to be deleted. Then notify the adapter using `notifyDataSetChanged()`. The adapter will refresh the ListView and your offending row will be deleted.

In your code, you're not storing the position of the current item in your view holder. Change it to this:

```
static class CitrusListHolder
{
    //TextView txtTitle;
    Spinner colorSpinner;
    Spinner textureSpinner;
    Spinner soliditySpinner;
    int currentPosition;
}
```

Then set the position in the holder

```
Button rateButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.rate_button);
        rateButton.setTag(position); //delete this line
        holder.currentPosition = position; //storing current position in holder
        rateButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CitrusListHolder currHolder = (CitrusListHolder) v.getParent().getTag(); //get button's parent which is the row
                data.remove(currHolder.currentPosition);  //get the stored position and remove the corresponding row
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

That should work.

Comment: Hrm. I added currentPosition to the holder, removed the rateButton.setTag line, set currentPosition = position, and tried index.currentPosition within onClick, but I'm getting "currentPosition cannot be resolved or is not a field." When I used holder.currentPosition (I made holder global), it does the same thing of only removing the last row in the list rather than the selected item.

Comment: I've edited the answer. You need to get the tag as a CitrusListHolder and not an integer. Set the holder back to it's non global state as well.

Comment: OK so I have this:
           CitrusListHolder currHolder = (CitrusListHolder) v.getTag();
data.remove(currHolder.currentPosition);
and it's crashing with a null pointer exception. Even if I just throw currholder.currentPosition into a toast, it crashes on the second line there.

Comment: You are still setting the tag to the row right?  row.setTag(holder);

Comment: Yes:

rateButton = (Button) row.findViewById(R.id.rate_button);
   holder.currentPosition = position;
   row.setTag(holder);

right above the click listener.

Comment: I think it's because `v` is referring to the button and not the row. Try the update I just made.

Comment: Same issue where it'll only delete the last item and not the selected issue. I think I may just scrap it and try again in the morning, see if I get any further or come up with a better way to structure it. Thank you for your help though, I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

You are not setting real position to the `Button`.

Move your `Button.setTag()` line from inside the `if` to outside of the `if-else` condition where the text and other data is being set. So after the scroll or refresh, it should get the real position on every call of `getView()` like this:

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    View row = convertView;
    CitrusListHolder holder = null;

    if(row == null)
    {
        //your implementation
    }
    else
    {
        //your implementation
    }

    CitrusList singleLine = data.get(position);
    //holder.txtTitle.setText(singleLine.title);
    rateButton.setTag(String.valueOf(position));  //<==== place it here, so it'll get the real/update position as tag, Convert it to String.
    return row;
}
```

and while getting it in `onClick()`. cast it to `String` then convert it to `Integer` like this:

```
int position = Integer.parseInt(v.getTag().toString());
```