# How do I roll out this view in my Android application?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I have a complex `ListView` involved layout in my Android project that looks something like the picture attached. The layout has a top, fixed part (the meeting details)  with `TextView`s `Join`, `Edit` and `Delete` that are clickable (really listen to `onTouch` events), with `Edit` and `Delete` only showing up for the meeting owner/creator.

There is, however, the `ListView` part below the fixed part as well, and this part has a number of unknown comments, presumably posted by people who have been invited to the meeting. Anyone whose account has access to this meeting, and who sees this layout can comment on this meeting information layout. However, only comments created by a person have the links `Edit` or `Delete` (again, `onTouch` listeners on those `TextView`s). In this way, think of this page as the detail page when you click on post in Facebook and you see all the comments posted, but are only able to edit/delete your own comments.

I thought I could set out with a solution like [this page](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/145373/android-listviews-with-dynamic-data/), with the top, fixed part and the `ListView` in the same fragment layout, but that will only work if I have the same links for all the comments. That is not the case for me, because the links `Edit` and `Delete` for each comment will only show up if the comment is by the comment author.

How should I do this? Do I have to write my own `Adapter`? Is that the only way? How would I go about writing my own `Adapter`? Any pointers/tutorials/links appreciated.

Lastly, I was wondering how I can set listeners for each clickable item on the comments. I know I have to use `setTag()` and `getTag()`, but don't know where to do this.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

[image: Complex Android listview layout]

Answer (score 0):

Vogella.com has some good android tutorials. [Here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown) is one for writing a custom adapter. [The android docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#HandlingUserSelections) also have a tutorial on listviews, but it doesn't look like they tell you how to do custom adapters. They do, however, tell you how to handle clicks on the list view.

You can setup your comment view to display the `Edit` and `Delete` buttons or not in the `getView()` method of your `BaseAdapter` class.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping for a little more pointers beyond this article.